# Creating Java nested FOR LOOPS and conditional statements without iterating over and over

Tags: java

I have created a login program that works. However, I am pulling my hair out trying to throw the code into one for loop that will iterate through the username string first. If the username is found then the program should enter a second for loop and then iterate through the password string. After both are found, then the program should compare both indexes if they are identical in order to receive a login message. If both dont match then an error message is thrown.

Because using nested loops became too hard for me to do without screwing up the logic of the code, I went ahead and separated the code and so far it works correctly.

Can someone show me how I can be able to consolidate this code ( the code under "//Write you code here ) into something more elegant?

```
import java.util.Scanner;  
class Challenge{  

 public static void main(String args[]){  
 Scanner i = new Scanner(System.in);  


 String user[] = new String[3] ;  
 String pass[] = new String[3] ;  

 user[0] = "John"; 
 user[1] = "Bob" ;  
 user[2] = "ArnoldSchwarzenegger" ;   

 pass[0] = "123"; 
 pass[1] = "456"; 
 pass[2] = "theterminator" ;   


 System.out.println("Enter username:");  
 String username = i.next(); 
 System.out.println("Enter pasword:");  
 String password = i.next();  

 ///{ write you code here    

int nameIndex = 0;
int copyK = 0;
String currentUser = "empty"; 

for(int j = 0; j < user.length; j++){

     if( username.equals(user[j])) {
         nameIndex = j;
         currentUser = user[j];
     }
}// end for loop

//Check Password

for(int k = 0; k < pass.length; k++){
    if (password.equals(pass[k]) && nameIndex == k){
        System.out.println("Hello " + currentUser+ "!" );
        copyK = k;
    }
} // end second for loop

 if ( nameIndex != copyK){
       System.out.println("Incorrect Login!");
 }else{ 
      System.out.println("Incorrect Login!");
 }


 ///}    


}  

}
```

Comment: Show us the code you have so far and we can help you from there.

Comment: It sounds like you should actually be using an array of classes.  Also, you should hash your passwords.

Comment: I don't see any need for any FOR loops at all, or iterating through the username string. All I see is a need to lookup the username somewhere and check the password somewhere else, or in some systems do them both at the same time. You haven't provided enough information to answer the question.

Comment: im trying to put it in but im confused with the formatting

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: I have pressed "ctrl+k" and tried to paste the code in but I think I am missing something.

Comment: @user3113390 paste your code, select all of it, and press `ctrl+k`

Comment: what is wrong with it?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with it in terms of compiling and running correctly. but I feel the code itself looks too "clunky." Would it be possible to next the for statements together and have the if statement inside the loop?

Comment: It's because im trying to learn Java for fun right now and although this program works, I am more interested in learning how to consolidate the current code you see which nested into the first for loop. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the length of `user[]` and `pass[]` is always equal, you can try this:

**Update:** This is much more simpler:

```
String currentUser = "empty"; 
boolean login=false;
for(int j = 0; j < user.length; j++){
    if( username.equals(user[j]) && password.equals(pass[j])){
        currentUser = user[j];
        login=true;
        break;
    }   
}
if(login)
    System.out.println("Hello " + currentUser+ "!" );
else
    System.out.println("Incorrect Login!" );
```

Comment: OMG thanks! I learned so much from this. Thanks for the expedited feedback!

Comment: you are welcome. you can simply combine the `if` statement inside `for` loop to make it shorter

Comment: Thanks for updating the code, I was wondering if you can combine into one if statement. Thanks much.